# Bootstrap form Add new record using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

i've tried looking at the source code and changing this but still have no luck! Hope someone can spot the mistake i've made.

Im basically just trying to submit a form with just 1 input field for now using AJAX and PHP to post using PDO method.

Here is my code:

Connection to database

```
<?php

define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME','test');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.HOST.'; port='.PORT.'; dbname='.DB_NAME;

try {
$bd = new PDO($dsn, USER, PASS);
//  $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATT_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Problem connecting to database, contact admin';
}

?>
```

Bootstrap Form

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Record</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<div class="form-group">
<form  id ="myform">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
</div>    
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

AJAX Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('ERROR');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

insert.php Script

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];


    $sql =  'INSERT INTO people(name) ';
    $sql .= ' VALUES (:name)';

    try {
        $query = $bd->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);


        if($query->execute()){
            echo "recorded added sucessfully";
        }else{
            echo "Problem adding new record";
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: not seeing anything in the console of the developers mode on the browser. My javascript is called before the the form as bellow :
 <script src="forminsert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: im now getting a pop up dialogue after submitting the form with blank msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html code, you don't have any *form*. So you can't directly use *.submit()* or *.serialize()*

> Consider closing you *form* elements within `<form>`

Change your html to this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Record</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<div class="form-group">
<form  id ="myform">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
</div>    
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
Add `name` attribute in `input` tag.
Serialize labels items by its name attribute.

Comment: Thanks. fixed the form tag but I am still unable to get the new record inserted into the database table

Comment: Add `name` attribute in `input`.
See updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about `submit()` to fully understand how it works: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

You are not using the `<form>` tag, so `submit()` doesn't catch any event. 
 Try wrapping your input and buttons in the same form tag, with `id=myform` and try again.

Also you are not using `event.preventDefault()`, without which the page will be refreshed.

Comment: sir i want to insert test data and image also with modal in php ajax, so how code will be modify, please help me.